# Finding formulas for the entries of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M = \begin{bmatrix}8&2\\-1&5\end{bmatrix}$ Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer
>
> $M^n = ?$ (Should be a $2 \times 2$ matrix)

What do they mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Often when you want to take a high power of a matrix $A$, you do what's called diagonalization. That is, you find two matrices $M$ and $D$ where $D$ is diagonal and $A = M D M^{-1}$. Then, we have that $A^n = (M D M^{-1})^n = M D^n M^{-1}$. Taking the power of a diagonal matrix is easy, so this is often a nice way to do this.

To add to this, in fact, $M$ and $D$ aren't some arbitrary matrices, the digonal entries of $D$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, and $M$'s columns are the corresponding eigenvectors. This decomposition (known as diagonalization) cannot always be done, but in your case is possible. It's helpful to note that any symmetric matrix can always be decomposed this way (though your matrix isn't symmetric) and moreover can be decomposed in such a way that $M^{-1} = M^T$.

Comment: I have found that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 7, \lambda_2 = 6$ what is my next step?

Comment: Find the eigenvectors corresponding to them, and then use that for the diagonalization. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization